# javafx format cells from ArrayList

Tags: arraylist, javafx, datepicker

I am working on a calendar application that shall retrieve date values from an ArrayList, which retrieves the string values from a SQL database. Formatting is achieved through a day cell factory.

Problem is that not only the dates from the ArrayList are formatted, by the cells of the whole month have a green background. Anyone has a hint of what I am doing wrong?

I started programming a year ago with Python and I am working with JavaFx for only a couple of months now, so my experiences with ArrayLists and cell factories are still quite limited.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Here is what I have so far ....

```
ObservableList<LocalDate> dates = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

       LocalDate date_1 = LocalDate.parse("2017-05-20");
       LocalDate date_2 = LocalDate.parse ("2017-05-18"); 
       dates.add(date_1);
       dates.add(date_2);

     Callback<DatePicker, DateCell> dayCellFactory = new Callback<DatePicker, DateCell>() {

         public DateCell call (final DatePicker datePicker ) {

             return new DateCell() {

                 @Override
                 public void updateItem (LocalDate item , boolean empty) {
                     super.updateItem(item, empty);

                     for (LocalDate ldt : dates) {
                         this.setStyle("-fx-background-color: green");
                         this.setTextFill(Color.BLACK);
                         this.setTooltip(new Tooltip("hello"));

                         }

                  };

             };

        };

    };


    dp.setDayCellFactory(dayCellFactory);  

    DatePickerSkin datePickerSkin = new DatePickerSkin(dp);
    Node popupContent = datePickerSkin.getPopupContent();
    calendar_pane_1.getChildren().add(popupContent);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your cell's `updateItem(...)` method:

```
 public void updateItem (LocalDate item , boolean empty) {
     super.updateItem(item, empty);

     for (LocalDate ldt : dates) {
         this.setStyle("-fx-background-color: green");
         this.setTextFill(Color.BLACK);
         this.setTooltip(new Tooltip("hello"));

     }

 }
```

sets the style of the cell so that it has a green background, *no matter the value of the `item` that is passed to the method*. (It even does it twice, since there are two elements in the `dates` list.) So clearly, every cell will have a green background.

You didn't state it in the question, but I'm guessing that you only want the items in your list to have the styled background. You need:

```
 public void updateItem (LocalDate item , boolean empty) {
     super.updateItem(item, empty);

     if (item != null && dates.contains(item)) {
         this.setStyle("-fx-background-color: green; -fx-text-fill: black ;");
         this.setTooltip(new Tooltip("hello"));

     } else {
         this.setStyle("");
         this.setTooltip(null);
     }

 }
```

Comment: @Rainer you should mark the answer as correct if it answers your question